# How to authenticate specific single page/URL in .htaccess and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I have Add htaccess authentication only for this URL "welcome/list" no another all pages/URLs

Answer (score 0):

```
#Set an environment variable for the URI you want to handle
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/welcome/list" welcome_list

AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd

Order Allow, Deny
Satisfy any
Allow all
Require valid-user

#Handle case 
Deny from env=welcome_list
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation